# JBoss-Logging and Apache Flume

Tags: java, logging, jboss, wildfly, flume

is it possible to integrate Apache Flume in JBoss-Logging? Could it be integrated as a custom-handler? The Server is a JBoss wildfly 8.1.0.

Thanks

Comment: I don't know much about flume, but how does it generally get the data? A `custom-handler` would definitely work.

Comment: flume is a framework/tool for collecting and aggregating log data. it is has a lot of pre defiened sources. log4j in version 2.x has a separate appender to use it but i am forced to use jboss-logging subsystem.

Comment: okay, i will try it with a little java.util.logging bridge to log4j and i will integrate some log4j and flume jars as modules in wildfly

Comment: Well you mainly just need to know how Apache Flume collects data. It's possible something would already work like a socket handler. It's pretty easy to make it work with the ELK stack http://wildfly.org/news/2015/07/25/Wildfly-And-ELK/

Comment: I Started with a Testapp and it worked brilliant. Thanks James. A simple socket Handler without hundreds of external libraries and APIs.